# How to detect coin transfer from transaction

Tags: ether

This is my transaction data. How to detect transfer coin from it (eth, bee, binance coin,...). Thanks.

```
 {
  "status": 200,
  "title": "OK",
  "description": "Successful request",
  "payload": {
    "blockNumber": "5855441",
    "confirmations": "2288758",
    "contractAddress": "null",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "1959743",
    "fee": "378000000000000",
    "from": {
      "address": "0xcc83dc5a37d49de4562019560307ce724a975d5c"
    },
    "gasLimit": "90000",
    "gasPrice": "18000000000",
    "gasUsed": "21000",
    "hash": "0xc935d22e20c77c3b249cfe002d98e1a3a95145760d8e84961e0356284a3ed358",
    "index": 61,
    "input": "0x",
    "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "nonce": "6712",
    "publicKey": "null",
    "r": "0x809d95f2aeb3e3de733e00d569a4bfa85b8165479289ad82c69718d81f3a0a1b",
    "raw": "null",
    "root": "null",
    "s": "0x37474c303ce60d31b4dddeefcae39951ecb947a0f1a72c079a4700223b2c5b56",
    "status": "0x1",
    "timestamp": "2018-06-26T04:01:25.000Z",
    "to": [
      {
        "address": "0x278aaf76ad2b1812f4fe161ec5d7ac99ebd524d6"
      }
    ],
    "v": "38",
    "value": "325000000000000000",
    "statusResult": {
      "code": "0x1",
      "confirmed": true,
      "success": true,
      "name": "successful"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Token transfers may be detected by looking at events logged by the transaction, though your transaction didn't log any, so there probably were no tokens transferred.

Ether transfers are harder to detect when ether is transferred by a smart contract, though your transaction trasferred ether from one externally owned address to another, i.e. neither transfer origin, nor transfer destination are smart contracts.  Such simple transfers are easy to detect by looking at transaction receipt:

```
"from": {
  "address": "0xcc83dc5a37d49de4562019560307ce724a975d5c"
},
"to": [
  {
    "address": "0x278aaf76ad2b1812f4fe161ec5d7ac99ebd524d6"
  }
],
"value": "325000000000000000",
```